# Postgres script - using "with" statement - want to export one of the with statements to file

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres installed on Linux server.

It uses the "with" statement in a script, abc.sql, as follows

start postgres sql script

```
with cte1 as (select …….), cte2 as (select …..) , cte3 as (select …..) 

Select from cte1 join cte2 …. join cte3...
```

end of script

The script works very well. It is called by a shell script and the output redirected to a file as follows:

```
pgsql -U tom -d db123 -f abc.sql > /tmp/output.txt
```

However I would like to output the results of "cte1" on its own to another output file.  At the moment I'm having to run this script (abc.sql, which already evaluates cte1) and then I have to run a second script (def.sql) which evaluates cte1 again (on its own) and sends its output to a separate output file.

Is it possible to evaluate cte1 only once (in the script abc.sql) but output the results to a separate file?  I was hoping to use the "\copy" option (in abc.sql) but it results in an error.

Hope I explained myself properly.

cheers

Comment: You might want to use a temporary table instead of a CTE. Also, [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer NO. A slightly longer answer, from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

> WITH provides a way to write auxiliary statements
> for use in a larger query. These statements, which are often referred
> to as Common Table Expressions or CTEs, can be thought of as defining
> temporary tables that ***exist just for one query***.  (Emphases Mine)

Basically your question is the same as asking if you can reuse a subselect in another statement. Cannot do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.  Yes I used temporary tables instead and they work a treat.

At the end of the sql script I can use two "\copy" statements to output to two different files. (Obviously the shell script not longer redirects the output and simply calls the sql script).

have a good day.